# Crystal Report for Asp Net Core 2.0 With Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to use crystal report in .net core 2.0 web application.

I have installed crystal report for vs2017, but not seeing option for adding crystal report in menu (add->new item->report).

Could anyone tell me if these are correct steps or is there any other way to use crystal reports with .net core 2.0 web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://www.sap.com/documents/2016/04/3050374d-6a7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html?_ga=2.115432454.1235774126.1517850270-610356991.1517850270), Crystal Reports does not support .NET Core. It is limited to the full .NET Framework versions 3.5 SP1, 4.5.2, and 4.6.

Comment: How about using it with a .NET Standard libary and referencing that library in .NET Core project? Would that work?